# Как обернуть собственную библиотеку в плагин?

Tags: python

Допустим я написал свою библиотеку на Python. Как мне затем обернуть ее в плагин, который другие смогут устанавливать и использовать ?

Comment: Может быть [пакет](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) вы имеете в виду?

Comment: from myFile import myClass

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Подготовка

1) Необходимо чтобы при импорте код не выполнялся

2) Определитесь как хотите распространять. Варианты: файловый архив, пакет python с установочным файлом, исходным кодом.

3) Напишите документацию, возможно это делать прямо в коде.

4) Приведите код к стандартам PEP

---

Упаковка

1) Вариант архива. Упаковать в zip, tar.gz. Выложить на стабильный хостинг. На этом все.

2) Исходным кодом. Удобно использовать специализированные площадки типа github, bitbucket. Преимущества. Возможно получать обратный отклик. Видны изменения.

3) Установочным пакетом. [Минимальная структура пакета](https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html). [Распространение на pypi](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/) python.

Естественно все варианты можно комбинировать при необходимости.

Comment: Таки можно еще распространять в виде пакетов к дистрибутивам, deb-package какой-нибудь.

Comment: из экзотики возможно и скопилированными (pyc, pyd, pyo) файлами распространять, отдельными под разные версии чтобы не отдавать исходный код.

Comment: @Igor необфусцированный pyc легко переводится в py. Не тот это язык, на котором легко спрятать код

Comment: скриптовые языки для этого и не предназначены, хотя усложнить жизнь тем кто не очень хорошо разбирается вполне возможно. Но это уже к другому вопросу о способах защиты.